# Adding Touch Event to UIVIew and passing an instance of UIView to called selector

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I am trying to associate an event to a `UIView`. This is possible via `touchesBegan` method and via `UIGestureRecognizer` but both ways are unable to send an instance of same `UIView` as a parameter to event selector. Can somebody tell me a suitable way to achieve this.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
This is the way I tried to put a `UIGestureRecognizer`. That in turn, call `expandActivity` method. But this method will not be anyhow able to pass `self.plannedActivityViewController.view` as `expandActivity` parameter. My aim is to play with the properties of `self.plannedActivityViewController.view`.

```
    UIGestureRecognizer *viewReongnizer = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(expandActivity)];
    [self.plannedActivityViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:viewReongnizer];
```

Comment: what have you tried? why do you want to send the instance? did you try sender.view?

Comment: question edited, please see now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (note the : after expandActivity)

```
UIGestureRecognizer *viewReongnizer = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(expandActivity:)];
[self.plannedActivityViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:viewReongnizer];
```

and then in expandActivity

```
-(void)expandActivity:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

//here you can use sender.view to get the touched view

}
```

Comment: thanks man! .. I was trying out a long way..adding notification and getting the object from notificationSender ..:P

Answer (score 0):

1. Subclass `UIWindow *` and use the subclass as the key window type in the application.
2. Implement `-(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method
3. From `event.allTouches` you can get a single `UITouch *` which will give you the `view` as it's property.